# problem of NDSolve with solving a simple BVP

Tags: differential-equations, singularity

I'm trying to solve a simple BVP of the following equation

$-10.625 + 16.75 u - 7.5 u^2 + u^3 + 4 e^{0.5(u-2.5)^2}f''(u) = 0$

on the interval of $[0,5]$ with boundary conditions

$f[0]=0$ and $f[5]=0$. It has an analytical solution which can be obtained by DSolve[]. However, when I solve it with NDSolve and compare the numerical solution with the analytical solution, the 3rd derivatives of the numerical solution f'''(u) always has a singular point at the left boundary u = 0. See the figure with the numerical solution in blue and analytical solution in orange.
[image: The blue is the numerical solution f'''(u) obtained by NDSolve, the orange is the analytical solution obtained by DSolve]

This is the code I use to get the numerical solution

```
eq = (-10.625 + 16.75 u - 7.5 u^2 + 1. u^3 + 4. Exp[(0.5 (-2.5 + u)^2)] f''[u]) == 0;
sol = NDSolve[{eq, f[0] == 0, f[5] == 0}, {f}, {u, 0, 5}, AccuracyGoal -> 11, InterpolationOrder -> 6];
g[u_] := Evaluate[f[u] /. sol];
Plot[g'''[u],{u,0,5}]
```

Comment: try making the range to start from a little less than 0.  `q = (-10.625 + 16.75 u - 7.5 u^2 + 1. u^3 + 
     4. Exp[(0.5 (-2.5 + u)^2)] f''[u]) == 0;
sol = NDSolve[{eq, f[0] == 0, f[5] == 0}, {f}, {u, -.1, 5}, 
   AccuracyGoal -> 11, InterpolationOrder -> 6];
g[u_] := Evaluate[f[u] /. sol];
Plot[g'''[u], {u, -.1, 1}]`  gives ![Mathematica graphics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/6syLK.png)

Comment: The plot looks normal, but if you look at g'''[0], it is still 0.4311. It becomes even more obvious when you make the plot range on [-0.01,0.01] instead of [-0.1,0.1]

Comment: You try to solve numerically a second order ode and expect smooth higher order slope f'''[u]?

Comment: The issue is that the numerical solution matches with the analytical solution pretty well, including derivatives up to order of 4, except at the boundary u = 0. This is what bothers me.

Comment: In addition, I don't see why it is impossible if the analytical solution is infinitely smooth.